# What is meant by domain in the notations of geometric deep learning?

Tags: terminology, geometric-deep-learning

While reading the `Notation` of the paper titled  [Geometric Deep Learning Grids, Groups, Graphs, Geodesics, and Gauges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.13478.pdf#page=7), I came across the following notations.

$$
\Omega = \text{ Domain} \\
 u = \text{Point on domain}
$$

I can only understand domain here as a set and point as an element in the set $\Omega$.

I have a simple doubt here.

Why do we call the set $\Omega$ as domain? Is it due to the notation related to [mathematical function](https://ncert.nic.in/pdf/publication/exemplarproblem/classXI/mathematics/keep202.pdf#page=2)?

$$\text{function_name} : \text{domain} \rightarrow \text{co_domain}$$

Or is it due to the usage of the word domain in the sense of application domain: [A specified sphere of activity or knowledge.](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/domain) such as computer vision, natural language processing etc?

or a combination of both?

Comment: Consider this example for an image, here domain is the grid(whole 2D grid), the function (image) is over this domain f(x,y), here a point  of this domain is (x,y).

Comment: So, it is same as the domain of a function right? @SwaksharDeb

Comment: We call it domain for mathematical scence like your first example

Comment: yes, it's the sample domain as we use in mathematics